# playn maven-install error

Tags: maven, playn

How do I overcome this error when I try to do a maven-install of playn-cute (I get the same thing when I do it on playn-project)?

```
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building PlayN Cute Flash 1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:unpack (unpack) @ playn-cute-flash ---
    [INFO] Configured Artifact: com.adobe.flex:flex-sdk:4.1.0.16076_mpl:zip
    SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
    SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
    SLF4J: See htttp://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
    Downloading: htttp://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/com/adobe/flex/flex-   sdk/4.1.0.16076_mpl/flex-sdk-4.1.0.16076_mpl.zip
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Summary:
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] PlayN Cute Metaproject ............................ SUCCESS [0.625s]
    [INFO] PlayN Cute Core ................................... SUCCESS [5.781s]
    [INFO] PlayN Cute HTML ................................... SUCCESS [54.125s]
    [INFO] PlayN Cute Flash .................................. FAILURE [23:58.047s]
    [INFO] PlayN Cute Android ................................ SKIPPED
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 25:01.422s
    [INFO] Finished at: Mon Oct 24 17:20:07 BST 2011
    [INFO] Final Memory: 9M/17M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-   plugin:2.1:unpack (unpack) on project playn-cute-flash: Unable to resolve artifact. Could not transfer artifact com.adobe.flex:flex-sdk:zip:4.1.0.16076_mpl from/to forplay-legacy (htttp://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo): No response received after 60000
    [ERROR] com.adobe.flex:flex-sdk:zip:4.1.0.16076_mpl
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
    [ERROR] forplay-legacy (htttp://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo, releases=true, snapshots=true),
    [ERROR] central (htttp://repo1.maven.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] htttp://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
    [ERROR]   mvn  -rf :playn-cute-flash
```

Note: due to my reputation I am only able to post questions with a maximum of two hyperlinks, the error output contained more, so each htttp above should actually read http.

Answer (score 1):

Inspect this error more closely:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-
 plugin:2.1:unpack (unpack) on project playn-cute-flash: Unable to resolve
 artifact. Could not transfer artifact
 com.adobe.flex:flex-sdk:zip:4.1.0.16076_mpl
 from/to forplay-legacy (htttp://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo):
 No response received after 60000
```

It says "No response received after 60000" which I suspect is a temporary outage of Google Code.

I just downloaded the file in question and it worked fine. So I suspect you simply need to try again.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply.  I had assumed the same thing and tried going in through the browser to directly download the file too - which I could (I had also tried running the code a number of times).  I'm using eclipse - any ideas where I could change the address for the plugin, and use a local address?

Comment: You could try running Maven from the command line once, which may download the necessary files into your local Maven repository, where Eclipse can access them. Just run `mvn install` in your top-level PlayN directory.